# Trying to add MSAL for android with android.support

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal

I have a library that needs to do login via azure , when I try to implement msal to it I get this error :

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
> is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-46:19 to override.

From my understanding (correct me if i'm wrong) it is caused because msal is using androidx and my main project is using android support ,

I can't migrate my project to androidx , any way to fix this issue ?

Many thanks!

Comment: What happens when you perform : add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-46:19 to override.

Comment: It says "Error running 'app': Default Activity not found